# cURL web services from iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, curl

I need to fetch data from curl web services from iOS, the client provided me a header name, header value and a base url, I dont know what to do with them, the url isn't giving me anything opening in a browser. They mentioned data is JSON encoded.

Please link me to some library or tutorial on how to call them.

Comment: You may want to read up on what HTTP POST is.

Comment: @H2CO3 i am iphone developer, i dont have much idea about web, please let me know how i can use them, so i will do what it takes, or will tell my colleague if it needs some web work, but i wanted to call them through iphone directly

Comment: I can't "just tell it", if you take iOS development seriously then you have to have some idea about HTTP.

Comment: You can run curl from terminal as well... What is your cURL ?

Comment: @Maulik yes its showing data in terminal, i am unable to make NSURLRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it, had to set NSURLRequest http method and header like

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request setValue:@"HEADER_VALUE" forHTTPHeaderField:@"HEADE_RNAME_"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) for cURL as well.

what I have used is:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url];

    __weak ASIHTTPRequest* request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    request.shouldPresentCredentialsBeforeChallenge = YES;
    [request appendPostData:[JSONString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setUsername:username];
    [request setPassword:password];

    [request setRequestMethod:@"PUT"];

    request.timeOutSeconds = 30;
    request.validatesSecureCertificate = NO;
 [request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: im using json library, i just changed the NSURL Request